# why router links does not work in React-js

Tags: reactjs, router

I am trying to link my navigation page to the homepage with route in react, but it gives me a blank page and no content. any idea what is wrong with my code? (I do not get any error)

App.js

[image: Code]

Home.js

[image: code]

Navbar.js

[image: code]

Comment: why do you have a route for Navbar? isn't it supposed to render on every page?

Comment: it wont change my problem either way.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `App.js` to this. Note the comments and add the `exact`. Hope this will solve your issue.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Home from './components/Home/Home';
import ( BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route
import Meny from './components/Meny/Meny';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar';

function App() {

return (
    <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
            <Route path='/' exact>
                <Home>
            </Route>
            <Route path='/navbar' exact> // Add exact here
                <navbar > 
            </Route>
            <Route path='/menu' component={Meny} exact/>  //Add exact here
        </Switch>
    </Router>
    )
} 
export default App
```

Comment: `exact` seems counter-intuitive.  Shouldn’t the OP remove the `exact` where it currently appears instead?